# Problem positioning div's next to each other within a parent

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm attempting to do something like the following. The container containing the 2 `div's` is of course `contentmain`.

```
 --------|-------
 |       |      |
 |       |      |
 |updates|tweet |
 |       |      |
 |       |      |
 |       |      |
 |_______|______|
```

There problem I'm having right now is updates is sprawling across the entire width for some reason. Also something worthy of note. All of this is inside another `div` called `contain`. Below is all the code involved.  I guess my question would be how do I achieve the above diagram while insuring that `contain`'s background expands over the content?

**HTML**

```
           <div id="contentmain">
        <br/>
            <div class="updates">
                <div id="banner"> Update: 31/12/10</div>
            <p> Content </p>
                <div id="banner"> Update: 31/12/10</div>
            <p> content2 </p>
            </div>
                <div class="tweet"> </div>
            <br/>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #contentmain { 
width: 800px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
    }

    #updates {
width: 400px;
float: left;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
    }

    .tweet .tweet_list, .query .tweet_list {
-webkit-border-radius: .5em;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #D8D8D8; 
}
.tweet .tweet_list .awesome, .tweet .tweet_list .epic, .query .tweet_list .awesome, .query .tweet_list .epic {
  text-transform: uppercase; }
.tweet .tweet_list li, .query .tweet_list li {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0; 
    }
  .tweet .tweet_list li a, .query .tweet_list li a {
    color: #0C717A;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.tweet .tweet_list .tweet_even, .query .tweet_list .tweet_even {
  background-color: #D8D8D8; }
.tweet .tweet_list .tweet_avatar, .query .tweet_list .tweet_avatar {
  padding-right: 5px; }
  .tweet .tweet_list .tweet_avatar img, .query .tweet_list .tweet_avatar img {
    vertical-align: middle; 
    }

    #contain {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
padding: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem is that you have element with class `updates` in html, but in CSS you style element with id `updates`: `#updates`.

When you're not sure what's going on with styles, try selecting the element in firebug and inspecting styles applied to it. Here you would see that `.updates` have none.
I find 'click the element in the page to inspect' option particularly useful: [image]

Comment: doh! that was the problem :) thanks.. ugh.. spent forever .. so simple.

Comment: @Ulkmun Do use firebug, it'll save you huge amount of time :)